# How can I make fields of a domain mandatory based on controller action?

Tags: grails, groovy

Is there a way to make domain fields mandatory depending on which controller action is hit by the user?

Example:

```
class Color {

  String name
  String shade

  static constraints{
    name nullable: true, blank: true
    shade nullable: true, blank: true
  }
}

class MyController {

  def save1() {
    //here I want only name field to be required
    Color c = new Color(params)
    c.save()
  }

  def save2() {
    //here I want only shade field to be required
    Color c = new Color(params)
    c.save()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option you have is something like this:

```
class MyController {

    def save1() {
        //here I want only name field to be required
        def color = new Color(params)
        if(color.validate(['name'])) {
            color.save(validate: false)
        }
    }

    def save2() {
        //here I want only shade field to be required
        def color = new Color(params)
        if(color.validate(['shade'])) {
            color.save(validate: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `CommandObject` and define your own constraints there

see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects

e.g.:

```
@grails.validation.Validateable
class ColorWithName {
    String name
    String shade

    static constraints = { 
        name(nullable: false, blank: false)
    } 
}

class ColorController {

    def save1(ColorWithName color) {
    if (color.hasErrors()) { ...
```

Comment: That can work but be aware that this is going to call for a new command object class to be written for each combination of validations that you want applied in different scenarios and you are still going to have to turn off validation when calling `.save()` on the real domain class.